# ActionBarSHerlock Tabs and Menu items: Customization

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have some question concerning that how to customize tabs and menu items - how to set margin between logo and tabs(where both of them are in one line) and how to put vertical separator between menu items which have only icons? (thing is that there is vertical separator when you present menu item as text or icon+text but not in case of icon only) Another thing concerning menu item`s separator is how to put this separator before each icon?

I have seen all actionbarsherlock samples where is quite a lot of styles for it and check another resources concerning it but I didn`t find how to custom these things.

Answer (score 0):

**Margin between tabs and logo**

Unless you create a custom view with your custom tab implementation there is only one way I can figure out to create a space between tabs and logo (assuming that the title is hidden) is setting the tab bar's left padding. For this your theme has to contain:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyTabBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyTabBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

The `MyTabBarStyle` has to contain:

```xml
<style name="MyTabBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar">
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/my_left_padding</item>
</style>
```

Note that you have to set this version of `MyTabBarStyle` in the proper place to be displayed only when the tabs are placed in the main action bar (which happens usually in the landscape orientation configuration), so you should place it in `res/values-land/styles.xml`.

**Menu items' dividers**

You mentioned correctly, that it is a problem to create dividers when the menu items are displayed as icons. You can still use little trick to do it - encode the dividers into action button backgrounds. If you use 9-patch drawables like this (scaled for better visibility):

[image]

then a green dividers will be created (naturally you should also create versions for other states).

To set the background, you have to define `android:actionButtonStyle` in the theme:

```xml
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyActionButtonStyle</item>
</style>
```

And the style has to have background defined:

```xml
<style name="MyActionButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/my_actionbutton_bg</item>
</style>
```

With this solution, you can place the divider before each item. Note that if overflow icon is displayed, you should probably define a similar background for `android:actionOverflowButtonStyle`.

A different solution to the problem might be to define `android:actionLayout` for menu items. There you can define your custom layout for each menu item.